# When Opening a 2010 Forms Project in Visual Studio 2012 I cannot View Existing Forms in the Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently upgraded from visual studio 2010 to 2012 and it seemed to work normally until I had to open a older project made using 2010. The Sln file appeared to load however the icon for Form1.cs in the solution no longer has the little icon indicating that it is a windows form additionally when i clicked on the Form1.Designer.cs the form was not loaded properly and instead i get a blank window that says To add components to your class, drag them from the Toolbox. however the form is not visible in the designer.

the program compiles fine and the form looks as it did but i cannot edit it except by manually changing the designer code I have no GUI editor

Comment: The project file was changed or damaged, it no longer has the proper elements to indicate that this is a form and the Designer.cs file is associated with it.  You left no clue to guess how that happened.  If you can't restore a good one from source control then fix it up by correcting the .csproj file with a text editor, use an existing known-good one to see what changes to make.

Comment: I checked the file and noticed that the subtype had changed from form to component however changing it back manually had no effect also the designer.cs for form1 appears to be completely intact as to how it happened the only thing i know is it worked in VS 2010 but when i installed and opened the project in VS 2012 it started doing this but to the best of my knowledge the project file hasn't changed


The project in it's entirety can be found here  https://github.com/mikeloeven/SBoxModList